# Unable to reinstall missing package after update to 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 20.04

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS. When updating it asked me to delete obsolete packages because new versions will be downloaded, I didn't give it much thought and deleted, Now when I try to run an application called xspec
an error started to occur:

```
xspec: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Apparently, now I have libreadline8, if I try to install libreadline7 by:

```
sudo apt install libreadline7
```

this happens:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libreadline7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libreadline7' has no installation candidate
```

My guess is it isn't available in the new repositories in 20.04 so I added this repository:

```
deb http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
```

But still the same error occurred, what should I do?

**P.S**
I have solved it by manually installing the package but I'd still like to know how can I install old 18.04 packages with `apt install` when I am on 20.04.

Comment: After you added the repo, did you remember to `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Yes I did, I have actually solved this by manually installing `libreadline7` but I'd still like to know why it didn't work when I added the repository

Comment: What is `xspec`? Can you get its new version? The 20.04 LTS uses `libreadline8`.

Comment: There isn't a newer version. Don't mind the specific application I just want to know in general how I would install old packages while newer packages exist.

Comment: How did U manually install libreadline7, can You pls share the steps or a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also trying to run these same Heasoft tools off Ubuntu 20.04.

I tried to manually install libreadline7 with the muon package manager however this solution did not work.

Instead, I manually installed libreadline7 from https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libreadline7/download then ran the usual `sudo dpkg -i libreadline7_7.0-3_amd64.deb`

You may have to install any missing dependencies but I didn't have any issues.

Xspec now runs perfectly!

```
$ xspec

        XSPEC version: 12.11.0
    Build Date/Time: Mon Apr 13 23:49:18 2020

XSPEC12>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually installing the package with the Muon Package Manager.

```
sudo apt install muon
```